# Two experiment variations do not appear in the table (Google Analytics)

Tags: google-analytics, type-conversion, tracking, web-analytics, ab-testing

I have started run one test. After few hours(3-9) I couldn't find any data capture under the "Conversions" section. But I can see some experiment sessions data under "Site Usage".

Even I have done the validation for both pages.

Experiment Code Validation
Original:
Experiment code found. Google Analytics code found.
Fake footer v1:
Google Analytics code found.

Please check the attachment.
[image: Conversions-Experiments Google Analytic]
[image: Site Usage GA]
NOTE: I got this kind of same problem in some other test. In that test I can see the data under the "Conversions" after one day. Seems its not showing frequently data with in few hours.

Please could you help to me to solve this issue.

Thanks,
Gopal

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.

I set up a test, an alternative page, and a goal.

mysite/xavier
mysite/magneto
mysite/t-rex

Xavier is my test page, Magneto is my alternative, and t-rex is my goal.

I'm using Drupal, so I installed the Google Content Experiments module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/content_experiments

This gives you a field on each content item where you can put the experiment key (equivalent, as far as I know, to adding the experiment code into the header of your page).

Couple of things worth noting that made it work for me:

1) You only put your code (or key) onto the text page - don't put it on the alternative or the goal

2) You have to wait a *good* 24 hours before you start to see data coming in

Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 5 hours can be a little bit short to measure CR changes. There are a few common things can can cause these issues. A lot of webmasters face problems because of the placement of the code in their header file. Below is a help file for installation on a WordPress site but I'm assuming the principles would be similar for any type of system you have setup. It outlines 4 problems and how to go about fixing each problem. I recommend you look at "Error #1 - Fix #2 or #3). https://www.atinyrhino.com/google-experiments-in-wordpress-not-working/

However, this could also just be a case of you needing to wait a little bit longer for the data to come in! Give it 24 hours before you panic!